# Is it a martingale?

Tags: expectation, self-learning, martingales

I need to show that the following is a martingale:

I know that $(X_i)_{i=0,1,...}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. r.v.'s with $E(X_i) = 0$ and $Var(X_i) = 4$. 
I need to show that $(S^2_n-4n)_{n=1,2,..}$ is a martingale (I remember that $S_n =$ sum of $X_i$).

So here I know that I need to show that $E(S^2_n-4n|F_{n-1})=S^2_{n-1}-4(n-1)$, where $F_n$ is the filtration.

Using independence, I get $E(S^2_n)-E(4n)$. I have the feeling that this $S^2_n$ should be a hint to use the info about the mean and the variance (because of the squared), but I don't see how I could do that.

Comment: **Hint:** $S_n^2 = S_{n - 1}^2 + 2 X_n S_{n - 1} + X_n^2$. Now use the properties of the conditional expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $Var(S_n)=E(S_n^2)$ since $S_n$ has expectation zero. 
Also, be aware that $S_n$ is not independent of $F_{n-1}$ since the first n-1 terms in the sum are measurable.
So what you want is actually:
$$E[S_n^2-4n|F_{n-1}]=E[(S_{n-1}+X_n)^2|F_{n-1}]-4n=E[S_{n-1}^2+2*S_{n-1}X_n+X_n^2|F_{n-1}]-4n$$
Now you can use that $S_{n-1}$ is $F_{n-1}$ measurable and $X_n$ is independent OF $F_{n-1}$. Can you finish the calculation from here?

Comment: I understand my mistake, it is of course $X_n$ and not $S_n$ that is independent of $F_n$. When you tell me that $S_{n-1}$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable I understand that I can take it out of the expectation.
Maybe I should just use it and not try to understand but why the formula of $S^2_n$ is linked with $S_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking but I think what you mean is that $E[S_n^2]=Var[S_n]=\sum_{k=1}^n Var(X_k)$ since the $X_n$ are independent?

Comment: I would calculate $E(S^2_{n-1}) + 2*E(S_{n-1})*E(X_n) + E(X_n)*E(X_n) - 4_n$ = $E(S^2_{n-1}) + 0 + 0 - 4_n$

Comment: Be aware that $E[S_{n-1}X_n|F_{n-1}]=S_{n-1}E[X_n]=0$ since again only $X_n$ is independent. Also, $E[S_{n-1}^2|F_{n-1}]=S_{n-1}^2$ by measuarbility. Moreover, $E[X_n^2]=Var(X_n)=4$ which is not zero since $E[X_n^2]$ is different from $E[X]*E[X]$ .

Comment: So if I write it I get $S^2_{n-1} + 2*E(S_{n-1})*0 + 4 - 4n $ = $S^2_{n-1} - 4(n-1)$, what I wanted. 
The key points that I lacked were the definition of $S^2_n$ and the measurability "trick". Thanks a lot for your help !